# how to call controller from renderer of actioncolumn in grid in extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

In extjs 4.1 i wish to have a button in my grid.

I've seen a few approaches such as using a renderer or a action column.  I've got this far.

The next step is that  i need to catch this event in my controller.

I've tried adding the following but it didn't get called

```
'#cutterGrid .editRow':{
                click:this.onCutterSelect
            },
```

I'll need to get the selected record.

-- Update

```
                    {
                        xtype:'actioncolumn',
                        width:20,
                        cls: 'rowEdit',
                        items: [{
                            icon: '/images/icons/layout_edit.png', 
                            tooltip: 'Edit'
                        }]
                    },
```

and in my controller

```
'#cutterGrid actioncolumn':{
                click:this.onCutterSelect
            },
```

and the function called

```
onCutterSelect : function(gridview, el, rowIndex, colIndex, e, rec, rowEl) {}
```

Comment: http://mitchellsimoens.com/2012/02/ext-js-4/actioncolumn-and-mvc/

Comment: thanks it works! if you add that as an answer i'll accept. I know i mentioned action column. though ideally i would just have  text ie "product 1". I guess i could use a renderer for this. But how would i catch this event in my controller with the record.

Comment: well I'm not sure this is the best practice, but you can use the `cellclick` event and use the `rel` attribute, for example, as the action name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Mitchell Simoens' Blog:

[ActionColumn and MVC](https://mitchellsimoens.com/actioncolumn-and-mvc/)

> ...So we chose to fire a custom event call ‘itemclick’, first we need
>   to decide what kind of arguments we want to fire this event with. The
>   scope of the handler is that of the ActionColumn which is where we are
>   going to fire the event on. We would maybe want the ActionColumn,
>   grid, rowIndex, colIndex, record, eventObject, the node clicked on and
>   since we are firing the event, we can make it easy on ourselves and
>   put a custom argument to tell the action we should take. Let’s look at
>   the code...